# angular 2 quickstart my-app template not displayed

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to learn angular 2, I am learning from the official website 5 min quick start https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

When I do npm start I get only **loading...** being displayed in the browser

I am using typescript 1.8
node 4.4.7
npm 2.15.8
using windows

[image: this is what is appearing on the command prompt]

has you can see from the above picture that it is not going to the app.component.ts file

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

my main.ts file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

my index.html file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

my app.component.ts file

The rest of the files are the same has given in the tutorial all config files.

Comment: Please share your `systemjs.config.js`

Comment: did you install required modules in your application by using command - `npm install` ?

Comment: You are using npm 2.15.8 version. Try upgrading npm to 3.x.x version